# Trying to list EC2 tags using Python but getting error: "errorMessage": "'NoneType' object is not iterable"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to list all EC2 tags. On other AWS account this works, but on another it doesn't.

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):


ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='eu-west-1')
ec2_list = ec2.instances.all()

for instance in ec2_list:
    for tag in instance.tags:
        print tag
```

I get the following error:

```
{
"stackTrace": [
[
  "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
  10,
  "lambda_handler",
  "for tag in instance.tags:"
]
],
"errorType": "TypeError",
"errorMessage": "'NoneType' object is not iterable"
}
```

Bit confused about how to solve this since everything is setup in a same way as it is on another account. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like `instance.tags` is `None`. Does one of the instances have no tags maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? You should check if the instances has any tags.

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='eu-west-1')
    ec2_list = ec2.instances.all()

    for instance in ec2_list:
        if instance.tags:
            for tag in instance.tags:
               print tag
        else:
            print "no tags"
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot! There was one instance without any tags.